# ODOO: How to trigger do_action by calling Javascript events without action_type button

Tags: javascript, odoo

I'd like to call a wizard in form view.But I do not want to use
`<button type='action' />`
Because it will trigger create method.

I have tried to use calling Javascript events.

```xml
<label string="search" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm open_the_door"/>
```

```
odoo.define('yc_root.my_JS', function (require) {"use strict";
    var FieldManagerMixin = require('web.FieldManagerMixin');
    var Widget = require('web.Widget');
    var bgdrawer = Widget.extend(FieldManagerMixin,{
        events: {
        "click .open_the_door": "_open_the_door",
        },
        init: function() {
            var self = this;
            self._super.apply(this, arguments);

        },
        _open_the_door: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var self = this;

            this.do_action({
                name: "settting search condition",
                res_model: 'my_wizard',
                res_id: self.id,
                views: [ [false, 'form']],
                type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
                view_type: "form",
                view_mode: "form",
                target:'new',
            });
        },
    });
    var my_widget = new bgdrawer(this);
    my_widget.appendTo($(".o_form_sheet"));
});
```

I expect it can open view as the pic.[image]

But it can not trigger.

Comment: You can not open non-stored model with `do_action` method. To do that you need to use object type button.

Comment: What do you mean of `open non-stored model`?  `res_model` is a transient model that still can store data temporarily.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the goal? what about use rpc to call a custom function in python?

Comment: object type button also triggers create.

Comment: You want to open wizard as in create mode right ?

Comment: yes, but not to save data after button click.

Comment: Can you explain bit more here what you want to do here and what you have done so far ?

Comment: As I posted, to call a wizard in form view( in here is a purchase model), this wizard can check some data(which have same conditions) and bring it out.